# Changing rows and colums of CSV in java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, row, move

I have been trying to get some help on manipulating a CSV file. I have looked through this forum and others for parsing CSV info into a new CSV file, but I dont think CSV works will rows and columns(im probably wrong).

Anyway I have a CSV that looks like this

```
\CAL 0.75-12188 06-28-2013 12-05.csv

0

6-28-2013 12-05
Serial Nbr,0.75-12188
Sales Order Nbr,23966
Model Nbr,3/4" LDP
Tag Name,LX-2-AHU-7H
Angle Offset,7.11
Overshoot,0
Flow Rate Closing,0.00000000,0.46367650,0.61821940,1.08192100,1.39102900,2.16381500,2.93662600,3.86397900,4.79133200,5.87325100,7.10973700,8.50076700,9.58268700,10.51004000,11.12828000,12.21020000,
Flow Rate Opening,0.00000000,0.46367650,0.61821940,1.08192100,1.23646200,2.00927400,2.62749100,3.55486900,4.48222200,5.40957500,6.49149300,7.72795900,8.80987500,9.58268700,10.66460000,11.90107000,
Flow Rate Ave,0.00000000,0.46367650,0.61821940,1.08192100,1.31374500,2.08654400,2.78205900,3.70942400,4.63677700,5.64141300,6.80061500,8.11436300,9.19628100,10.04636000,10.89644000,12.05564000,
Angle Closing,18.67788000,24.13643000,29.82170000,35.43774000,41.11793000,46.74594000,52.17502000,57.80665000,63.35862000,68.93623000,74.51913000,80.14727000,85.78853000,91.05897000,95.72566000,100.62130000,
Angle Opening,18.67518000,23.91829000,29.50020000,35.29157000,40.52844000,46.27448000,51.63242000,57.84357000,63.00760000,68.66663000,74.01138000,79.50329000,85.10954000,90.60167000,96.38528000,100.58310000,
Angle Ave,18.67653000,24.02736000,29.66095000,35.36465000,40.82319000,46.51021000,51.90372000,57.82511000,63.18311000,68.80144000,74.26526000,79.82528000,85.44904000,90.83032000,96.05547000,100.60220000,
```

and I want it to look like this (I think its a different file, but all files are the same length and size.)

```
Serial #    Model # Tag Name    Angle Offset    Flow Rate Ave [val 1]   Flow Rate Ave [val 2]   Flow Rate Ave [val 15]
0.75-12188  3/4" LDP    LX-2-AHU-7H 7.11    0   0.4636765   10.89644
0.75-12192  0.75 LDP - 11   NC-P-AHU-4H 12.92   0   0.3091087   11.20555
```

You will notice that there are flow rates val 1, 2, 15... etc... this represents the 15th value under flow rate or 2nd or 1st.

I have been noticing that I may need to add to the api something like opencsv

so I basically want the serial in 0,0 the model number is 0,1  angle offset in 0,2  etc
then the values should correspond with this data.

Thanks so much, so far I have only been able to get csv merge, the only problem is that they are all goofy like my first example, so before I merge i want to clean it up like this.

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: If this is a one-time need, I'd open the file in Excel and manipulate it there.

Comment: Sorry about the last example, the flow rate ave [Val 1] should correspond with the 0's next to it, the reason it doesnt match is because the file I copied it from was an xls and not csv. The end file should be a csv therefore there should be commas between it.\

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with all the variables you have listed ie `Serial Number, Model Number ...etc`.

As the constructor for that object you could parse in the filename, the constructor would then read the file and populate the object as needed, something like...

```
public YourObject(String filename)
{
    try
    {
       //Create a file reader
       BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); 
       // Read each line and treat appropriately
       String line;
       while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null)
       {
            String[] splArry = line.split(",");
            if(splArry.length > 1)
            {
                 // set fields appropriately here
            }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could then create a method to build a csv string, something like

```
public String toCSVString()
{
     String out = "";
     out += serailNumber + "\t"; // or what ever delimiter you want
     //... etc for all your fields
     return out;
}
```

Then if you have a folder with all these files you just construct an object for each object, add it to a list then for each object in your list call your CSVString method and append that to your master csv file.

```
File folder = new File("The folder where your files are")
Files[] files = folder.listFiles();
for(File f: files)
{
    YourObject yourOb = new YourObject(f.getName()); //just realised propbably would be better to create constructer which takes file not the filename;
    String csv = yourObj.toCSVString();  // and then wrtie this to your new csv file 
}
```